# Installed 13.04 clean on a machine that used to run 12.10. No longer boots

Tags: installation, laptop, 13.04, toshiba

64-bit.

I was doing fine with 12.10 but I read that 13.04 took care of a few of the more sluggish aspects of 12.10 so I decided to upgrade.

The installation package seemed significantly less smooth than 12.10- instead of a snappy, smooth experience it had a few graphical bugs and took a LONG time to load, with various pools of unresponsiveness. Regardless, I went through with it.

Now, unless I boot from USB from the BIOS menu, the computer simply does not boot Ubuntu. I re-installed, to no effect. There is just a single flickering `|` on the top-left. Randomly pressing keys, after the first 7 or so, starts producing system beeps. The system is not completely unresponsive: It turns the screen on-and-off if I press "Ctrl+Alt+Del".

Pressing shift makes no difference.

hardware info: Tecra M11. Nvidia Quadro NVS 150m. 4gb RAM.

Comment: Provide details (add to question) of hardware brand/model.

Comment: Tecra M11. Nvidia Quadro 150. 4gb RAM.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug with the kernel that effects nvidia drivers
You can either upgrade to [saucy](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2138987) or use a [mainline kernel](https://github.com/GM-Script-Writer-62850/Ubuntu-Mainline-Kernel-Updater#readme)

I would use a live cd to edit my `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` file and change every `timeout=0` to `timeout=10`
This way I will have a chance to push keys during boot
This command should get the job done:
`sudo sed -i 's/timeout=0/timeout=10/' /media/$USER/*/boot/grub/grub.cfg`
you will need to mount the partition with `/boot` on it.

Comment: trying this out ASAP

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting to the grub boot selection screen? 
Or does it get stuck before then?
If it gets stuck before loading grub you probably need to reinstall grub.

Comment: No boot selection screen at all.

Literally the most powerless computer interface I've ever handled in my life. It's a blinking carat that beeps or reacts to CAD.

I re-downloaded the image on a windows computer and used a different program to burn it to USB. It *feels* slightly better this time around, but it could be all placebo.

Please do tell me how to reinstall grub in case I reach another dead-end.

Comment: Ok, its a bit tricky but if you read it carefully it should work just fine. Hopefully grub is the only thing that has messed up : ) Here is an article that explains how to: http://opensource-sidh.blogspot.co.nz/2011/06/recover-grub-live-ubuntu-cd-pendrive.html